# Cross object values are accessed as Null values in Test class

Tags: unit-test

I have 3 objects
ObjA, ObjB, ObjC - these three objects have relation like ObjA > ObjB > ObjC
ObjB have a lookup field for ObjA
ObjC have a lookup field of ObjB

Created on validation rule in object ObjC, code is in below
ISBLANK( ObjB__r.ObjA__c )

In my test class i have inserted 3 object records and i am trying to fetch id of ObjA from ObjC but getting null Value and getting validation error while inserting a record in ObjC

```
@isTest
private class MyTestClass {      
    @isTest static void myTest() {

        objA__c a = new objA__c(name='test1');
        insert a;

        objA__c a1 = [Select id,name from objA__c  where name='test1' limit 1];

        objB__c b = new objB__c(name='test2',objA__c=a1.id);
        insert b;

        objB__c b1 = [Select id, name, objA__c, objA__r.id from objB__c  where name='test2' limit 1];

        objC__c c = new objC__c(name='test3',objB__c=b1.id);
        System.debug('A object ID in C obj'+c.objB__r.objA__c); // Here getting value as Null - Throwing validation error
        insert c; // Not able to insert his DML    

    }
}
```

Comment: Is it null pointer exception or Validation error? can you also provide error message

Comment: You do not need to query again after the insert. The ID is populated after each insert. Maybe, it is falling at insert b;.

Answer (score 0):

I can see why you are getting null pointer exception.

You have not inserted recorc C, and you are trying to access cross object field objB__r.objA__c without inserting and querrying it out.

A fix would be to insert first and querry later.

```
objC__c c = new objC__c(name='test3',objB__c=b1.id);

insert c; // Not able to insert his DML    

objC__c c1 =[Select id,Name,objB__r.objA__c where Id=:c.Id];


System.debug('A object ID in C obj'+c1.objB__r.objA__c); // WOuld pribt value
```

**Further impovement**: You dont need to do a querry if you are using just ID field after insert/upsert

```
@isTest
private class MyTestClass {      
    @isTest static void myTest() {

        objA__c a = new objA__c(name='test1');
        insert a;      

        objB__c b = new objB__c(name='test2',objA__c=a.id);
        insert b;


        objC__c c = new objC__c(name='test3',objB__c=b.id);        
        insert c; // Not able to insert his DML    


        objC__c c1 =[Select id,Name,objB__r.objA__c where Id=:c.Id];
        System.debug('A object ID in C obj'+c1.objB__r.objA__c); // WOuld pribt value

    }
}
```

Src: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_testing/apex_testing_intro

Comment: he could also do objC__c(name='test3',objB__r=b); so that all fields in object b are available through object c, even before insert of c

Comment: I have missed one info related to Validation rule, which has created in ObjC
Rule is : ISBLANK( ObjB__r.ObjA__c )
Can you please tell me is there any case to fair this validation rule before insert of ObjC.
I have the same scenario in my real objects with real test class,
There my validation rule is fairing before insert of leaf child object (ObjC).
this validation rule stops the execution of test class.